# Performing threshold operation on an RGB image

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, intel-ipp

I need to perform a threshold operation on an RGB image. The thresholding that I intend to do should behave as follows.

If greyscale equivalent of a pixel ( calculated as `0.299 * R' + 0.587 * G' + 0.114 * B'` ) is `Y`, then the pixel value of the output image will be:

```
P = Threshold_color, if Y < threshold_value
  = (R,G,B), Original value
```

,where Threshold_color is an RGB color value,

I wanted to perform this operation using Intel IPP library. There I found few API's related to [thresholding of images](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-threshold-1). (`ippiThreshold_LTVal_8u_C3R`)

But these methods seems to work only on one data point at a time. But the thresholding that I want to do depends on the combination of 3 different values (R, G, B).
Is there a way to achieve this through IPP library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested approach:

1. Copy the image into a greyscale image
2. Create a binary mask 0/1 (same size as greyscale image) using the threshold
3. Multiply this mask with the replacement color you want to generate an overlay
4. Apply the overlay to the original image.

Note that you're generating images of different types here: first greyscale, then black&white, and finally color images again (although in step 3 it's a monochromatic image)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an approach. I was able to get the required result using following IPP api's.
[Color to Gray Conversion: ippiColorToGray_<mod>]
[Applying threshold on Gray image to get monochromatic image : ippiLUTPalette_<mod>]

[Merging the threshoild and source image: ippiAlphaComp_<mod>.]

In order to get the correct merging I also set the correct alpha for the Thresholded image and the source image using ippiSet_.
I couldn't find an API that would generate a bitmask from a Gray scale image. So I just used a normal 8-bit depth image instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can implement this using IPP but I'm not aware of any standard function that does what you want.

All IPP threshold operations I can find in the reference use a global threshold.

Comment: I am new to using IPP in programming. Can you suggest a pseudo code for achieving the result through IPP? Just the steps would suffice. I just need to know what all features pertaining to my requirement are available in IPP.

Comment: @sajas calculate the grayvalue for each pixel, then compare it vs your threshold and assign the output pixel accordingly. you can do this in many ways, using LUTs or arrithmetic operations or simple if statements in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and accept the answer once successful.